# Proving $\lim_{x \to 1} \left (\tan \left(\frac{\pi x}{2} \right ) \lfloor x \rfloor \right )$ doesn't exist

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm asked to prove that the following limit doesn't exist:
$$\lim_{x \to 1} \left (\tan \left(\frac{\pi x}{2} \right ) \lfloor x \rfloor \right )$$

My attempt was to break the case into one-sided limits. So, for example, I could prove that

$$\lim_{x \to 1^+} \tan \left(\frac{\pi x}{2} \right ) = -\infty$$

and
$$\lim_{x \to 1^-} \tan \left(\frac{\pi x}{2} \right ) = \infty$$

and then show that $$\lim_{x \to 1^+} \left (\tan \left(\frac{\pi x}{2} \right ) \lfloor x \rfloor \right ) \neq \lim_{x \to 1^-} \left (\tan \left(\frac{\pi x}{2} \right ) \lfloor x \rfloor \right )$$

using the product rule for infinite limits.

The only problem is that I'm not allowed to use the theorem about the limit of a composition of functions ($g(t)=\pi t /2$ and $f(x)=\tan{x}$) nor any theorem related to the limit of a continuous function when proving $\lim_{x \to 1^+} \tan \left(\frac{\pi x}{2} \right ) = -\infty$. I can however use the fact that $\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}^+}\tan x=-\infty$ and $\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}^-}\tan x=\infty$. Is there any way I can prove it using the basic limit arithemtic rules?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Hint.** You may observe that, as $x \to 1$,
$$
\tan \left( \frac \pi2x\right)=-\frac{2}{\pi  (x-1)}+\mathcal{O}(x-1) \tag1
$$ and that
$$\lfloor x \rfloor =\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } x \to 1^+ \\
   0       & \text{if } x \to 1^-
  \end{cases}$$ giving
$$\tan \left( \frac \pi2x\right)\lfloor x \rfloor \to\begin{cases}
-\infty & \text{if } x \to 1^+ \\
   0       & \text{if } x \to 1^-
  \end{cases}$$ thus **a limit doesn't exist** as $x \to 1$.

---

To see $(1)$, we may write, as $x \to 1$,
$$
\begin{align}
\tan \left( \frac \pi2x\right)&=\tan \left( \frac \pi2(x-1)+\frac \pi2\right)\\\\&=\frac{\cos\frac \pi2(x-1)}{-\sin\frac \pi2(x-1)}\\\\
&=\frac{1+\mathcal{O}((x-1)^2)}{-\sin\frac \pi2(x-1)}\\\\
&=\frac{1+\mathcal{O}((x-1)^2)}{-\frac \pi2(x-1)+\mathcal{O}((x-1)^3)}\\\\
&=-\frac{2}{\pi  (x-1)}+\mathcal{O}(x-1).
\end{align}$$

---

> The notation $$\displaystyle f(x)=\mathcal{O}((x-x_0)^n)$$ means that there exists some constant $C$ around $x_0$ such that  $$\displaystyle |f(x)|\leq C|x-x_0|^n$$ for all $x$ in a neighbourhood of $x_0$.

Comment: Thank you. My main question is about the limit of $\tan \left(x \pi/2 \right)$ (the rest in easy). I can't use the first equation (otherwise I must prove it first).

Comment: @user239211 Ok, let me add some details. Thanks.

Comment: @OlivierOloa I am just curious, what does the O(x-1) term represent? Is it the rest of the taylor expansion of tan(pi/2 x)? Thanks.

Comment: Thank you @OlivierOloa . Great proof.

Comment: @user239211 You are welcome!

Comment: @CivilSigma Please see my edit. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You already have it...almost !

For $\;x\;$ pretty close to $\;1\;$ **from the right**,

$$\;\lfloor x\rfloor=1\implies \tan\dfrac{\pi x}2\lfloor x\rfloor=\tan\dfrac{\pi x}2\to-\infty\;$$

and from $\;x\;$ very close to $\;1\;$ **from the left** you get

$$\lfloor x\rfloor=0\;\implies \tan\dfrac{\pi x}2\lfloor x\rfloor=0\to 0$$

Comment: Please read my question again. The whole point is proving that $\tan \frac{\pi x}{2}$ goes to $\pm \infty$ (depends on the side) using the most basic tools.

Comment: Isn't that what I did?? Besides this fact, what's so special in the limit of $\;\tan\dfrac{\pi x}2\;$ ? It is just a rather well known trigonometric function approaching one of its infinite vertical asymptotes. You yourself mention this as something you can use...

Comment: No. I said that I can use $\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}^+}\tan x=-\infty$. I know that this is the same as $\lim_{x \to 1+}\tan \left( \frac{\pi x}{2} \right)$ but I must prove it first. Until then these are, formally, different limits.

Comment: @user239211 What do you mean "you must prove it first"?? If  $\;\lim f(x)\;$ exists when $\;x\to x_0\;$ , then it exists and equals the same **no matter how** $\;x\;$ **approaches** $\;x_0\;$ ...this is basic limits theory, well before trying exercises as the one you posted...

Comment: don't you see that $\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}^+}\tan x$ and $\lim_{x \to 1+}\tan \left( \frac{\pi x}{2} \right)$ are formally different limits? Can't you understand that you must **prove** that they are the same? That's how math works. You must prove things. You didn't prove anywhere that $\tan\dfrac{\pi x}2\to-\infty\;$. You just said that it is a "rather well known trigonometric function" and completely ignored my question. Yes, I know that intuitively these are the same limits but intuition is not a proof. I'm sorry for you that you don't understand that.

Comment: @user239211 Whatever: that's not the way I studied it nor the way I'd teach it. For me, one of the first things to do with limits is to show that **if** the limit exists then it exists *no matter how the variable approaches* the desired point. That is **exactly** what you have here, when instead of having $\;\lim_{x\to\pi/2}\tan x\;$ you have $\;\lim_{x\to 1}\tan\frac{\pi x}2\;$ . No intuition! in particular that  other answer uses Taylor expansions' approximations, which are waay after limits and derivatives are studied. It doesn't matter, though: you've been answered to your satisfaction.

Comment: user239211, sorry to intervene, but @Timbuc tried to help you, he has no reason to help you, instead of saying thanks because something trying to help, you want to seems clever... "I'm sorry for you that you don't understand that",  I think you already knew the answer to your question, I don't like this guys who want to make clever with something, I'm sorry if you don't understand what I want to tell you ;)

Comment: @Lucas - I was very nice to him even though he didn't answer my question. But then he decided to argue with me about the limit being "easy", "and rather well known". He didn' even consider that _maybe_ my calculus course is a bit different (in order of theorems). He didn't even **read** my question. I was asking how to prove $\lim_{x \to 1^+} \tan \left(\frac{\pi x}{2} \right ) = -\infty$. He **didn't** prove it. Instead, he showed me the "answer" which I actually already knew (he **assumed** that $\lim_{x \to 1^+} \tan \left(\frac{\pi x}{2} \right ) = -\infty$).